# Datastax Agent 5.1.3 Short os-stats collector failed

Tags: cassandra, opscenter, datastax-enterprise

after starting datastax agent 5.1.3 on our new servers we are getting following error in the agent.log.

```
ERROR [os-metrics-6] 2015-08-05 13:49:41,565 Short os-stats collector failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.ops(Numbers.java:942)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.lt(Numbers.java:219)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.min(Numbers.java:4007)
    at opsagent.rollup$add_value.invoke(rollup.clj:156)
    at opsagent.rollup$process_keypair$fn__1435.invoke(rollup.clj:235)
    at opsagent.cache$update_cache_value_default$fn__1163$fn__1164.invoke(cache.clj:25)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at clojure.lang.Ref.alter(Ref.java:174)
    at clojure.core$alter.doInvoke(core.clj:2244)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at opsagent.cache$update_cache_value_default$fn__1163.invoke(cache.clj:25)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
    at clojure.lang.LockingTransaction.run(LockingTransaction.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LockingTransaction.runInTransaction(LockingTransaction.java:231)
    at opsagent.cache$update_cache_value_default.invoke(cache.clj:24)
    at opsagent.rollup$process_keypair.invoke(rollup.clj:235)
    at opsagent.rollup$process_metric_map.invoke(rollup.clj:241)
    at opsagent.os.collection$start_os_stat_collection$send_metric__15899.invoke(collection.clj:80)
    at opsagent.os.linux_metrics$sendmap.invoke(linux_metrics.clj:12)
    at opsagent.os.linux_metrics$report_mem_stats.invoke(linux_metrics.clj:134)
    at opsagent.os.linux_metrics$collectors$wrap_short_collector__9128$fn__9129.invoke(linux_metrics.clj:270)
    at opsagent.os.collection$start_pool$fn__15870.invoke(collection.clj:39)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Apart from that everythings seems to work fine.

OS: RedHat 7.1
Datastax Agent: 5.1.3 rpm installed from datastax repo
System on LVM
Commitlog and Data Directory on different disks without LVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a known issue (internal number is OPSC-3293) that is going to be fixed in the upcoming OpsCenter 5.1.4. It’s usually intermittent, and should not affect metric collection.